# Grouping in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

There is an array of objects (Zakazchik):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *zakazchikFavoritesArray;
```

Each object has field `@property int zakazchikCategory` and can vary from 1 to 23 inclusive.

How can I create a TableView, so grouping it was on this field?

**ADDED:**

in viewDidLoad (after filling zakazchikFavoritesArray):

```
dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (Zakazchik *object in zakazchikFavoritesArray) {
    NSMutableArray *categoryArray = dataDictionary[@(object.zakazchikCategory)];
    if (categoryArray == nil) {
        categoryArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        dataDictionary[@(object.zakazchikCategory)] = categoryArray;
    }
    [categoryArray addObject:object];
}
```

also:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return dataDictionary.count;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *array = dataDictionary[@(section)];
    return array.count;
}


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Zakazchik *object = dataDictionary[@(indexPath.section)][@(indexPath.row)];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ZakazchikCellFavorites";
ZakazchikCellFavorites *customCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

customCell.zakazchikName.text = object.zakazchikName;

return customCell;
}


-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
Zakazchik *object = dataDictionary[@(section)];

return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", object.zakazchikCategory];
}
```

i got error:

```
2015-05-30 myApp[12521:484566] -[__NSArrayM zakazchikCategory]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b735f00
2015-05-30 myApp[12521:484566] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM zakazchikCategory]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b735f00'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to first organize your data in to a new data structure that sorts them by the category property. I would recommend using a dictionary that maps from category to an array of all objects that have that category value. You can transform your data like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (Zakazchik *object in zArray) {
    NSMutableArray *categoryArray = dataDictionary[@(object.category)];
    if (categoryArray == nil) {
        categoryArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        dataDictionary[@(object.zakazchikCategory)] = categoryArray;
    }
    [categoryArray addObject:object];
}
```

Then use this data structure when implementing your UITableView data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return dataDictionary.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *array = dataDictionary[@(section)];
    return array.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Zakazchik *object = dataDictionary[@(indexPath.section)][@(indexPath.row)];

   // Create your cell using the object..
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *array = dataDictionary[@(section)];
    Zakazchik *firstObject = [array firstObject];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", firstObject.zakazchikCategory];
}
```

Comment: The error was being thrown in your `titleForHeaderInSection:` method. `dataDictionary` holds arrays of objects, not objects directly. You need to access the array first. Then since you know all the objects in that section have the same category you can just pull the `zakazchikCategory` property from the first object.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid error you can rewrite this method as follow

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   NSMutableArray *objectArray = dataDictionary[@(section)]; // not needed 
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Category #%i", section];
}
```

Because your `dataDictionary` contains arrays of `Zakazchik` not objects directly  and, I guess you have another table/array with names of categories so in this method no reason to select this object